# AVAudioRecorder stop method iOS 6.1.x issue

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, avaudiorecorder

in my app, when I want to stop an audio recorder, works fine for iOS 5 an 6.0.x

`[self.audioRecorder stop];`

calling to the method  `audioRecorderDidFinishRecording`

But in iOS 6.1.x, doesn't.

The app get stuck, and doesnt call to `audioRecorderDidFinishRecording`

any ideas? please

Comment: does any have any idea?